# In which microservice should I store a liaison table

Tags: relational-database, relationship, microservices

I'm splitting my zoo-management application into micro-services.
I have the following domain : animals, caretakers, cages

I thinking about where I should store the relationships.

For exemple a cage contain several animals :
Should I store the cage_animals table into the cages services database or into the animals database ?

And several caretakers are attributed to several animals :
Should I store the caretakers_animals table into the caretakers service's database or into the animals service's database ?

Comment: Yes there are rules about which animal species can go into which cages: it depends of the cage itself and also of the animals already in the cage. Cages also have their own rules independent of animals (to schedule checks, cleaning, etc..).

Comment: I think you should split the services by the different animals. They are microservices after all. So you would have the Elephants Service, the Penguins Service, and the Tiger Service! That would be so cool!

Comment: Thank you for the Link Ryan

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add this as a comment but I hit the character limit :-)

If the behavior of the cage is different for different types of cages, maybe each of them needs to be a different type of cage resource in your cages microservice. Each type of cage will then enforce whatever rules it needs to follow.

The issue of where to persist the relationships with microservices is a complex one with no one size fits all answer. My preference is to try to have loose coupling as much as you can. Only when absolutely necessary, each resource should store it's relationships to other resources and in a *uni-directional* way. What happens when relationships get updated somewhere else? one way is to inform the related services (through messaging perhaps?) so they do the right thing for their own resources.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it is a matter of awareness : I decided it was ok for cages to be aware of what an animal is. So the cages service will hold the relationship to animals. The animals service will be oblivious about the concept of cages.

Comment: Exactly! each microservice only need to maintain the relationships that are required by it in a uni-directional way. But make sure that early on you build the mechanism to keep data consistency (like the messaging example I mentioned above)

Answer (score 0):

I'd [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42449160/architecture-for-communication-between-two-microservices) I think.

Maybe together we'll have a complete response :)

I'm using JHipster to generate my application.

Comment: You're also writing zoo software? Cool!